# ImageView setsetImageResource keeps crashing on phone but not on emulator or tablet

Tags: android, android-resources, android-image

Developing a poker game, where I have 5 cards displayed initially with back of a card. Then will display the first set with new images of a card and still okay. Upon drawing for another card, the `setImageResource()` triggered `InvocationTargetException` while `debugging` using phone. And when running in phone, it crashed with `IllegalStateException` could not execute method for android `onClick()`. Sometimes it crashed on the second card, or 3rd or 4th card. No pattern. I don't encounter this using `emulator` or my `tablet`. Happening only on my 2 phones. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
07-23 18:59:52.967 11643-11643/com.seanwilliam.pokersingle E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.seanwilliam.pokersingle, PID: 11643
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:389)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5619)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22298)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6365)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:883)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5619) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22298) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6365) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:883) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773) 
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 26269068 byte allocation with 3836592 free bytes and 3MB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:624)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:457)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1152)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.createFromResourceStream(ResourcesImpl.java:1272)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:743)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:585)
    at android.content.res.MiuiResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(MiuiResourcesImpl.java:308)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:785)
    at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:534)
    at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:358)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:198)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
    at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:85)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:93)
    at com.seanwilliam.pokersingle.MainActivity.Draw(MainActivity.java:207)
    at com.seanwilliam.pokersingle.MainActivity.btnChange(MainActivity.java:98)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5619) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22298) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6365) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:883) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773) 


    int[] imgCard = [R.drawable.c_ac, R.drawable.c_ad, R.drawable.c_ah, R.drawable.c_as,
        R.drawable.c_2c, R.drawable.c_2d, R.drawable.c_2h, R.drawable.c_2s,
        R.drawable.c_3c, R.drawable.c_3d, R.drawable.c_3h, R.drawable.c_3s,
        R.drawable.c_4c, R.drawable.c_4d, R.drawable.c_4h, R.drawable.c_4s,
        R.drawable.c_5c, R.drawable.c_5d, R.drawable.c_5h, R.drawable.c_5s,
        R.drawable.c_6c, R.drawable.c_6d, R.drawable.c_6h, R.drawable.c_6s,
        R.drawable.c_7c, R.drawable.c_7d, R.drawable.c_7h, R.drawable.c_7s,
        R.drawable.c_8c, R.drawable.c_8d, R.drawable.c_8h, R.drawable.c_8s,
        R.drawable.c_9c, R.drawable.c_9d, R.drawable.c_9h, R.drawable.c_9s,
        R.drawable.c_10c, R.drawable.c_10d, R.drawable.c_10h, R.drawable.c_10s,
        R.drawable.c_jc, R.drawable.c_jd, R.drawable.c_jh, R.drawable.c_js,
        R.drawable.c_qc, R.drawable.c_qd, R.drawable.c_qh, R.drawable.c_qs,
        R.drawable.c_kc, R.drawable.c_kd, R.drawable.c_kh, R.drawable.c_ks];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    card1= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card1);
    card2= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card2);
    card3= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card3);
    card4= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card4);
    card5= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card5);

    hold1= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hold1);
    hold2= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hold2);
    hold3= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hold3);
    hold4= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hold4);
    hold5= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hold5);

}


public void btnChange(View view) {
    if (bDeal) {
        NewDeal();
    }else {
        Draw();
    }
    bDeal= ! bDeal;
}



public void NewDeal (){

    hold1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    hold2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    hold3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    hold4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    hold5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    card1.setImageResource(R.drawable.c_blue_back);
    card2.setImageResource(R.drawable.c_blue_back);
    card3.setImageResource(R.drawable.c_blue_back);
    card4.setImageResource(R.drawable.c_blue_back);
    card5.setImageResource(R.drawable.c_blue_back);


        cardNo[0]=-1;
        cardNo[1]=-1;
        cardNo[2]=-1;
        cardNo[3]=-1;
        cardNo[4]=-1;

        GenerateCards();

        bHold1 =false;bHold2 =false;bHold3 =false;bHold4 =false;bHold5 =false;
        sKind[0]="";sKind[1]="";sKind[2]="";sKind[3]="";sKind[4]="";
        iCard[0]=0;iCard[1]=0;iCard[2]=0;iCard[3]=0;iCard[4]=0;
        int iC1, iC2, iC3, iC4, iC5;
        iC1=cardNo[0];
        iC2=cardNo[1];
        iC3=cardNo[2];
        iC4=cardNo[3];
        iC5=cardNo[4];

        card1.setImageResource(imgCard[iC1]);
        card2.setImageResource(imgCard[iC2]);
        card3.setImageResource(imgCard[iC3]);
        card4.setImageResource(imgCard[iC4]);
        card5.setImageResource(imgCard[iC5]);

}


public void Draw () {
    if (!bHold1) {
        cardNo[0] = -1;
    }
    if (!bHold2) {
        cardNo[1] = -1;
    }
    if (!bHold3) {
        cardNo[2] = -1;
    }
    if (!bHold4) {
        cardNo[3] = -1;
    }
    if (!bHold5) {
        cardNo[4] = -1;
    }

    //Get random number
    GenerateCards();

    //bHold1 =false;bHold2 =false;bHold3 =false;bHold4 =false;bHold5 =false;
    sKind[0] = "";
    sKind[1] = "";
    sKind[2] = "";
    sKind[3] = "";
    sKind[4] = "";
    iCard[0] = 0;
    iCard[1] = 0;
    iCard[2] = 0;
    iCard[3] = 0;
    iCard[4] = 0;
    int iC1, iC2, iC3, iC4, iC5;
    iC1 = cardNo[0];
    iC2 = cardNo[1];
    iC3 = cardNo[2];
    iC4 = cardNo[3];
    iC5 = cardNo[4];

    if (!bHold1) {
        card1.setImageResource(imgCard[iC1]);    <--sometimes this is the error
    }

    if (!bHold2) {
        card2.setImageResource(imgCard[iC2]); <--sometimes this is the error
    }

    if (!bHold3) {
        card3.setImageResource(imgCard[iC3]); <--sometimes this is the error
    }

    if (!bHold4) {
        card4.setImageResource(imgCard[iC4]); <--sometimes this is the error
    }

    if (!bHold5) {
            card5.setImageResource(imgCard[iC5]);
    }


}
```

Comment: Could you post the stack trace of the crashes?

Comment: Would you please provide code you tried ?

Comment: What parameter are you giving to setImageResource? Give us more detail about your code

Answer (score 1):

It is out of memory issue, OOM

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 26269068 byte allocation with 3836592 free bytes and 3MB until OOM
```

I'm not sure how you create the images and load it, some codes will be helpful. And general speaking, let library such as Glide to handle the image loading. These libraries do size sampling and reduces the size when loading the image. It greatly reduce OOM issues.

Comment: weird, since I can run this app in a low end tablet without error but only experiencing it using 2 high end phones with large enough memory. Also,  I tried to create a new project with only 5 imageviews (without all the codes) changing its image using setimageresource with no problem at all. Anyway thanks for the reply btw the code is listed below the logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code below :

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("yourpackagename:drawable/" + StringGenerated, null, null);
imageview.setImageResource(id);
```

or use this

```
Drawable image = ImageOperations(context,ed.toString(),"image.jpg");
ImageView imgView = new ImageView(context);
imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
imgView.setImageDrawable(image);
```

Comment: I also tried this approach and I experienced the same error. Thanks for the reply